# Confuse about browser garbage collection algorithm

Tags: algorithm, browser, garbage-collection

According to the [Javascript: the definitive guide](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch11_03.htm), there are two garbage collection ways:

the `Mark-and-Sweep` and `Reference Counting`, and in the early browser, garbage collection is performed by reference counting.

But why they turn to the `Mark and sweep`? I think the collection situation is the same, when one value is unreachable, its reference count is zero.

So what is the difference?

Comment: Oh, a JavaScript book. How cute. Don't belive 'em. (There are far more than two GC algorithms.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about history.


Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference counting is a simple heuristic for finding garbage objects, but it's not perfect. In particular, reference counting can lead to *reference cycles*, where a cycle of unreachable objects all point to one another. When this happens, all of the refcounts for the objects are nonzero, so the objects are never cleaned up, although the objects are indeed garbage. Firefox 2 used pure reference counting for its garbage collection, which over time led to enormous memory leaks as reference cycles began eating up all of memory.

Mark-and-sweep doesn't have this problem because it explicitly finds all reachable objects starting from all known reachable locations. It can handle reference cycles perfectly, though it's slower to run. The combination of reference counting (fast but inaccurate) plus mark-and-sweep (slow but perfect) is a good compromise.

That said, there are much better GC techniques out there. Search "generational garbage collection" for some of the better hybrid techniques.

Hope this helps!